# Android шрифт для всех локалей

Tags: локализация, android, шрифты

Я использую не андроидовский шрифт для получения текущего месяца используя DateFormatSymbols, то есть класс отдает мне месяц на языке в зависимости от локали, получается мне нужен шрифт поддерживающий все локали? Что делать в таком случае? Испльзовать шрифт по умолчанию?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. искать шрифт который для всех
       локалей один
2. хранить список локалей с которыми
       умеет работать шрифт и если текущей
       локали нет в списке, то выдавать другой шрифт (тоже с проверкой)
       или использовать стандартный